# Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome Keyboard Layout US International without AltGr

Tags: 18.04, gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My keyboard layout in Gnome is currently configured like this:

```
[org/gnome/desktop/input-sources]
sources=[('xkb', 'us+altgr-intl')]
```

For some reason, when I type `'` and press `e`, it doesn't make this: `é`. I also can't find the right keyboard layout to achieve this, it only works with AltGr for some reason.

Comment: You probably want the `us+intl` layout instead.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Seem to work indeed, strange, it wasn't before.. Thanks alot

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried many layout from Settings->Region&Language->Input Source, including all English US layout having intl. in their name, even after enabling extended input sources in gnome-twaks. But I can not get `é` just typing `'` and then `e` as usual. @Sander where do you write the Gnome configuration? The search `grep -R 'input-sources' ~/.*` gives me no results.